# inserting mutiple rows from one form not working

Tags: php, pdo

This is what i have changed it to, still nothing - no errors, runs the $_POST and just doesnt insert anything.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO appts (trainer, date, time, name, phone, club, group_key) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($train, $_POST['date'], $time, $_POST['name'][$i], $_POST['phone'][$i], $club, $group_key));
```

I've recently switched to PDO as i finally got my hosting upgraded, and i'm having issues trying to insert multiple rows into my db off of one form. If anyone can see what i'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated!

what the code is trying to do: Form for number of clients -> loop to generate a group of inputs equal to number of clients just entered -> insert all of these into the database (time is only being put into the first one, others time is left blank)

```
if($action == 'group'){
echo "Number of clients: <form method='post'><input type='text' name='num' value='$_POST[num]'><input type='submit' value='Go' name='group'></form>";
if($_POST['group']){
    $num = $_POST['num'];
    ?>
    <form method='post'>
        <br>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Time:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='time'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <?
            if(!$trainer){

                $q = $db->prepare("SELECT name from trainers where club = '$club'");
                $q->execute();
                echo "<td>Trainer:</td> <td><select name='trainer'><option value=''></option>"; 
                while($row = $q->fetch()){
                    echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[name]</option>";
                }
                echo "</select></td>";
                }
            for($i = 1; $i < $_POST['num'] +1; $i++){
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>Name $i: </td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='name[]'>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp; &nbsp; Phone:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='phone[]'></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                        ";
            } 
            ?>
        </table>
        <input type='submit' name='addgroup'>
    </form>
    <?
    if($_POST['addgroup']){
        $group_key = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST['name']); $i++){
            $time = '';
            if($i = 0){
                $time = $_POST['time'];
            }
            if($trainer){
                $train = $trainer;
            }
            else{
                $train = $_POST['trainer'];
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO appts SET trainer = ?, date = ?, time = ?, name = ?, phone = ?, club = ?, group_key = '$group_key'";
            $q = $db->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($train, $_POST['date'], $time, $_POST['name'][$i], $_POST['phone'][$i], $club));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you do $worked = $q->execute();
var_dump($worked), what does it say ?

Comment: @metareviewr Doesn't say anything

Comment: @metareviewr i feel like its an issue with the loop, it seems like ABSOLUTELY nothing is happening, not that its not inserting. `$i < sizeof($_POST['name']);` seems like its producing 0 inside of the query set of code, but if i put it elsewhere it produces the correct number

Comment: @robz228, you should check if its getting inside the loop, if it is then check if the `execute` is working, try: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Somehow I also cannot find closing braces for your first if.  Please check that as well.

Comment: $q = $db->prepare("SELECT name from trainers where club = '$club'");
                $q->execute();

That's no good... You need to move your variable to execute() to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: @vinodadhikary i didnt copy down far enough when i pasted, theres 4 in a row on the bottom

Comment: Are you sure that query returns anything @robz228

Comment: @metareviewr `$club` comes from a config. not generated user-side

Comment: @metareviewr yes, [link](http://ffimgmt.com/pt/?step=appointments&trainer=&date=2013-08-15&sub=newappt&action=group) if you want to look at it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i ended up rebuilding printing results step by step to see where it was breaking. i had `if($i = 0)` which should have been `if($i == 0)` (duh). always the little thing. heres what i ended up using:

```
if($_POST['addgroup']){ 
    $group_key = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
    if(!isset($_GET['trainer'])){
        $train = $_POST['trainer'];
    }
    else{
        $train = $_GET['trainer'];
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['name']); $i++){
        $time = '';
        if($i == 0){
            $time = $_POST['time'];
        }
        $data = array($train, $date, $time, $_POST['name'][$i], $_POST['phone'][$i], $club, $group_key);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO appts (trainer, date, time, name, phone, club, group_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute($data);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your insert query does not look right.  Try the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO appts (trainer, date, time, name, phone, club, group_key) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '$group_key')";
```

You should also move the `$group_key` in the `array` that you are passing to `execute` method.  Don't know why you had it in the `$sql`, so I left it as is.

Comment: why is $group_key in there ?

Comment: Not you could, you should.

Comment: Does it actually matter though? I'll switch it because it makes more sense, but i just assumed it only matters to use ? for values that are user-generated since something like $group_key could not possibly create an injection

Comment: I guess there is little chance of any potential harm doing there but I guess it's just about showing the proper way to do things... so others might not think this is okay to do with any var.

Comment: @metareviewr gotchya, however, its still not working. edited with what i have at top of code

Comment: @robz228, I had to edit my code because I found a missing comma between `value and group_key`, please give it a try again.

Comment: @vinodadhikary i was aware, and i'm  not sure where `value` came from, it should have been `club` anyways :P

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query isn't good.

```
INSERT INTO  appts (trainer, etc) VALUES (?,?)
```

or

```
UPDATE appts SET trainer = ? WHERE something = ?
```